# Need guidance simplifying $\iint (2-x^4-y^4)\sqrt{6-x^2} \,d\mathbf A$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

we have 
$$\iint (2-x^4-y^4)\sqrt{6-x^2} \, d\mathbf A \qquad(-1\le x \le 1), \quad(-1\le y \le 1)$$

i have attempted converting to polar coordinates and got
$$\iint (2-(r\cos(\theta))^4)-(r\sin(\theta))^4)\sqrt{6-(r\cos(\theta))^2}(r) \, d\mathbf A$$
However it doesnt simplify nicely and i am having a hard time seeing where to go from here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**thanks**

Comment: Perhaps mention the region over which to integrate.

Comment: corrected the code

Comment: The limits of integration in polar coordinates become rather tricky. However, you can use symmetry to reduce to two integrals, with $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$ and $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$. Then you have to figure out the $r$ limits. But the integral is horrendous. Where did this problem come from? You put the divergence theorem as a tag. Perhaps you should edit your question to include the *original* question.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- Without region $A$ (you can do this), integrate first respect to $y$ so you have
$$y\int2x^4\sqrt{6-x^2}dx- \frac {y^5}{5}\int\sqrt{6-x^2}dx+ax+b$$ and
$$y\int2x^4\sqrt{6-x^2}dx=\frac{yx}{2}\sqrt{6-x^2}(x^2-3)+9\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt6}\right)+c$$ Try to calculate the second integral and evaluation over the region 
$(-1\le x \le 1)(-1\le y \le 1)$ to finish.